# NSUserDefaults properly storing Strings in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type

So I set up a NSUserDefault to store a string in my GameViewController

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("_1", forKey: "SkinSuffix")
```

The idea is it stores a suffix which I will attach to the end of an image name in order to save what skin of a character the player should use.

When I call the value in my GameScene class like so

```
var SkinSuffix = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("SkinSuffix")
println(SkinSuffix)
```

it prints "Optional("_1")" instead of just "_1" so when I try to change the name of my image file like so, it doesn't load the image file

```
hero = SKSpriteNode(texture: heroAtlas.textureNamed("10Xmini_wizard\(SkinSuffix)"))
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you know what optionals are in Swift? `stringForKey()` returns a `String?` - are you aware what the question mark stands for?

Comment: Basically it means that it can handle an answer that does/doesn't exist (nil) right? And the unwrapping basically makes an optional not optional... saying that it must have a value (can't be nil). Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unwrap the **String** using the **Optional Binding** construct. This avoids a crash of the app if the value is nil.

```
if let skinSuffix = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("SkinSuffix") {
    println(skinSuffix)
}
```

**Update:** As correctly suggested in the comment below, I am putting the retrieved value in a constant (let). We should always use constants when we don't need to change the value. This way the Swift compiler can make some optimizations and does prevent us from changing that value.

Comment: Better:`if let ...` unless you really need a variable.

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's implicitly an optional not of type `String`. You need to case it as such or unwrap the optional in your `println` statement.

```
var SkinSuffix = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("SkinSuffix") as! String
```

Or in your `println`: `println(SkinSuffix!)`

As a side note, you should you camelCase for your variable names.

Comment: Throws an error saying "Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: Yah I had to unwrap it, the as! String doesn't work but all I had to do was unwrap it at the end like NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringforKey("SkinSuffix")!

Comment: Forced unwrapping with `!` is not the optimal solution. This will crash at runtime if no value is set for this key.

Comment: And what is camelCase?

Comment: @Martin that shouldn't be a problem as I give it a default value at the GameViewController unless I am misunderstanding? What would be optimal then?

Comment: Unless you are 100% sure that a value is set (*and* has the correct type String) you should use optional binding with `if let` for "test and unwrap".

Answer (score 0):

You can use "??" Nil Coalescing Operator to help you dealing with nil and it also 
allows you to specify a default string value.

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject("_1", forKey: "SkinSuffix")

let skinSuffix = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("SkinSuffix") ?? ""
println(skinSuffix) // "_1"
```